# Vertical scroll bar specifying percentage

Tags: html, css

I need a vertical scroll bar by specifying the height and width in %.. Not in px..  please check this link,  of my website, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FLlvG ...
 I want a scroll bar in the leftcontent

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question here is one of the solutions to the problem

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li> line 1 </li>
            <li> line 2 </li>
            <li> line 3 </li>
            <li> line 4 </li>
            <li> line 5 </li>
            <li> line 6 </li>
            <li> line 7 </li>
            <li> line 8 </li>
            <li> line 9 </li>
            <li> line 10 </li>
            <li> line 11 </li>
            <li> line 12 </li>
            <li> line 13 </li>
            <li> line 14 </li>
            <li> line 15 </li>
            <li> line 16 </li>
            <li> line 17 </li>
            <li> line 18 </li>
            <li> line 19 </li>
            <li> line 20 </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  #container { width:500px; border:3px solid red; margin:0 auto; position:relative; }

    #sidebar { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:150px; height:100%; background-color:yellow; overflow-y:scroll; }

    #main { margin-left:150px; }

    p, ul { padding:10px; }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TUwej/2/)

Comment: Thanks !! I don't want to specify the height and width in px.. I want to achieve a scroll bar by specifying width=40% and height=100%..

Answer (score 0):

> The default of `height` and `width` is `auto`. For `height`, length is
>   determined by the content of the container, and for `width`, length is
>   determined by horizontal space available in the screen.

Therefore, to use height property in percent(`%`) in a container, you should give the parent element a height in other units(`px`,`pt`).

---

Fix your CSS(in [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FLlvG)) like this:

```
.content {height: 150px;}
.leftcontent {height: 50%;}
```

Comment: @user3496655 I hope this CSS will fix your problem.

Comment: How do I specify 100% height of parent content? I want to use 100% height  html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }

Answer (score 0):

Check this jsfiddle.net/Yajju/ . I've only added inline css in html.

Comment: Thanks,that kind of helped me, but not 100%... What i am specifically looking for is, width=40% and height=100%, i need a scroll bar in the left content...